# I have a large Chinese text file and I want to reformat it into individual lines, each ending with a period

Tags: python, cjk

I want to separate this file into lines (each ending with a period (question mark, exclamation point, etc)) in order to make it easier to work with later on.

I attempted to use nltk, but to no avail:

```
text = r'你在哪里？ 我想看到你的狗！我很喜欢你。'
tokenized_text=sent_tokenize(text)
print(tokenized_text)
```

Actual result:
`['你在哪里？ 我想看到你的狗！我很喜欢你。']`

Expected result:

`['你在哪里？
我想看到你的狗!
我很喜欢你。']`

Comment: Are there spaces in between all the lines you'd like to seperate?

Comment: try this: `text_tokens = re.split(r'[？！]', text)`

Comment: @AlphaTested sometimes there are, but not always

Comment: @dopstar That yields the same result as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seeing as how no one has responded...

```
import re
text = r'你在哪里？ 我想看到你的狗！我很喜欢你。'
text_tokens = re.findall(r'(.*?[？！。])\s?', text) #with all the seperating tokens between []
print("\n".join(text_tokens))
```

outputs

```
你在哪里？
我想看到你的狗！
我很喜欢你。
```

explanation `.+?` looks for one to infinity characters up to the first occurrence of
`[？！。]` any of the tokens you want to split on
`(previous)\s?`  stripping any excess spaces if it exists. by only capturing the text and token

`"\n".join(text_tokens)` joins the list to a newline/formats each match as a new line.

if you were reading it from a file to another file a really simple program could look like this

```
import re
text_tokens = []
with open("example.txt", 'r') as text:
    text_tokens = re.findall(r'(.+?[？！。])\s?', text.read())
with open("output.txt", 'w+') as out:
    out.write("\n".join(text_tokens))
```